# How to appendchild for htmlelement at special index

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, appendchild, htmlelements

I am using the .NET WebBrowser control to as a WYSIWYG html editor.
Now i want to replace special string in htmlelement With a Link.
I was using from this code

```
foreach (var el in nodes)
{
    string innertxt = el.InnerText;
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(innertxt, pattern);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        string finalLink = FinalWordLink(word_current, linkTemp);
        int indexWord = match.Index;
        int lenghWord = match.Length;
        el.InnerText = el.InnerText.Remove(indexWord, lenghWord);
        el.InnerText = el.InnerText.Insert(indexWord, finalLink);
    }
}
```

But I now that's not work and show new link as a text
I have a problem, I don't want replace innerhtml because this is not good and maybe replace wrong string like tag,class,etc
I know how can i append child in htmlelement Like this :

```
HtmlElement elem = HTMLEditor.Document.CreateElement("a");
elem.SetAttribute("href", "www.google.com");
elem.InnerText = "Click here";

el.AppendChild(elem);
```

But how can I appendchild at find index ?